# How to explicitly set the color to transparent/nothing in the options of mdframed?

Tags: color, mdframed

Is it possible to explicitly set the `backgroundcolor` option in `mdframed` package, so that the background stays transparent (or, let's say "empty")?

It could be

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgrouncolor = ***]
Test
\end{mdframed}
```

with `***` = `no color`, `empty`, `{}` but none of those work.

**Is it possible to explicitly set the color to transparent/nothing in the options of mdframed?**

---

### edit

To say it more explicitly, is there a value `***` such that

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgrouncolor = ***]
Test
\end{mdframed}
```

and

```
% assuming no global options have been set
\begin{mdframed}
Test
\end{mdframed}
```

are equivalent?

Comment: I've updated my answer; however, I'm still not sure I understood your question after the edit. Is something like that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple and "illegal" solution

You have to use `backgroundcolor = none`. This is an "illegal solution" because `none` does not exit. So, `backgroundcolor = none` is the same as `backgroundcolor = frogs`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = none]
Test
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Complicated and "legal" solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\begin{mdframed}[apptotikzsetting={%
    \tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={fill=red,fill opacity=0}}}]
Test
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure I understand the question, so I present three possible answers:

#### First option:

You can use `\mdfsetup` to define global settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=red!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
test
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Second option:

By default, in the initial configurations, `mdframed` sets the background color to `white`, so

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white]
test
\end{mdframed}
```

and

```
\begin{mdframed}
test
\end{mdframed}
```

are equivalent; notice that the default background color isn't really transparent, it is white and there's no predefined key to set the opacity for the background color (for a solution to the transparency issue using `tcolorbox` see third option below).

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white]
test
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}
test
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

are equivalent.

#### Third option:

I don't recall `mdframed` offers a way to set the background opacity (but I might be wrong). With [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) you can control the background and/ot frame opacity using `opacityframe=<value>`, `opacityback=<value>` (`0` means completely transparent, `1` means opaque); A little example (`\pagecolor{cyan!10}` was used only to make the opcity effect visible):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\pagecolor{cyan!10}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  standard jigsaw,
  opacityframe=0.5,
  opacityback=0.2
]
test
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you answer my question. I thought the background color by default was "transparent":I thought that if the background of the whole page was red then the background of the frame would be red as well.

Comment: @Colas unfortunately, as I said, `mdframed` doesn't offer a kpredefined key for this transparency option. `tcolorbox` does.

Comment: Hi, I think the answer is actually `backgroundcolor=none`.

Comment: @Colas you are wrong. unless you define it, there is no such thing as `none` if you were to specify `mdfsetup` in the preamble. There is a `white`, like @Gonzalo pointed out, but that's about it.

Comment: OK, you are right ;-) My solution works, though. A working solution which is correct is by using `tikz`.

Comment: See my update for a legal solution.